# Find consecutive alphabets in string

Tags: python, string

I want to find consecutive number of characters and print them as >3 with alphabets#count otherwise print all alphabets
I want to get: B#6CCCBBB

But I get B#5CCCBBB as output. I am missing 0th element.

```
str1 = "BBBBBBCCCBBB"
def consecutive_alpha(str1):   
count = 0
new_string = ""
n = 3
for i in range(0, len(str1)-1):
    if str1[i] == str1[i+1]:
        count += 1
        if i == (len(str1)-2):
            if count > n:                
                new_string = new_string + str1[i] +"#" + str(count)
            else:
                new_string = new_string + str1[i]*count
    else:
        if count > n:                
            new_string = new_string + str1[i] +"#" + str(count)
        else:
            new_string = new_string + str1[i]*count
        count = 1            
print new_string


consecutive_alpha(str1)
```

Comment: Fix your indentation please.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `itertools.groupby`?

```
from itertools import groupby

def strict_groupby(iterable, **kwargs):
    for key, group in groupby(iterable, **kwargs):
        yield (key, ''.join(group))

def consecutive_alpha(string):
    return ''.join(f'{key}#{len(group)}' 
                   if len(group) > 3 
                   else group 
                   for key, group in strict_groupby(string))

consecutive_alpha('BBBBBBCCCBBB')
```

Output:

```
'B#6CCCBBB'
```

Answer (score 2):

Incase want to try one-liner

```
from itertools import groupby
''.join(_ + '#' + str(len(l)) if len(l)> 3 else ''.join(l) for l in [list(g) for _,g in groupby(str1)])
#B#6CCCBBB
```

Comment: You could use `_` quite effectively here instead of `l[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `B#5` because you initialize `count = 0`. So you're not counting the first character. You get it right when you do `count = 1` later in the loop.

You have another problem. If the last character isn't part of a repeated sequence, you never print it, since the loop stops early.

```
def consecutive_alpha(str1):
    count = 1
    new_string = ""
    n = 3
    for i in range(0, len(str1)-1):
        if str1[i] == str1[i+1]:
            count += 1
            if i == (len(str1)-2):
                if count > n:
                    new_string += str1[i] +"#" + str(count)
                else:
                    new_string += str1[i]*count
        else:
            if count > n:
                new_string += str1[i] + "#" + str(count)
            else:
                new_string += str1[i]*count
            count = 1
    # Add last character if necessary
    if len(str1) > 1 and str1[-1] != str1[-2]:
        new_string += str1[-1]
    print(new_string)

consecutive_alpha("BBBBBBCCCBBBD")
consecutive_alpha("BBBBBBCCCAAAABBBXXXXX")
```